# is it possible to open multi profiles on the same window?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla, add-on

i know that i can open multiple profiles (different proxies), every profile in a firefox window, 
with many extentions or with commande "-P {PROFILENAME} -no-remote".

i would ask if it's possible to open multiple profiles in same window, every profile in one tab (thinking about having someone develop a custom extention).

thanx guys

Comment: As written, this does not appear to be a programming specific question.  As such: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to fake it by making one Firefox window the parent of another. I did a quick proof of concept using [`SetParent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541(v=vs.85).aspx) on two Firefox windows running in separate processes with different profile paths:

[image: foxception]

The inner window is definitely a sub-window of the outer window here. For example, if you try to maximise the inner window it simply expands to fill the outer window.

However, you can't a window a child of a tab, because a tab is not a window. To achieve the illusion of having the window embedded in a tab, you'd have to listen for when the current tab changes (`gBrowser.tabContainer.addEventListener("TabSelect", f)`) and switch to the correct sub-window for that tab. You can use [`SetWindowPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) to resize and reposition the sub-window to fill the tab content area.

To slice off the chrome elements (window border, toolbars, etc.) you could either use [`SetWindowRgn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145102(v=vs.85).aspx) or perhaps delete those elements from the DOM of the sub-window.

You would also have to make sure the Firefox sub-processes get closed when the corresponding tab is closed.

Note that you can do all this from JavaScript using the foreign-function-interface: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes

---

This may be a dodgy-arse solution, but honestly I can't think of anything else that could possibly be better, apart from re-evaluating your requirements. Firefox simply isn't designed to deal with more than one profile per process.